# Filter groups based on comparison of multiple rows within each group: BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

SQL newbie here.
My table has 4 columns.
`Date`, `A`, `B`, and `Count`.
If I group by A and B, there are 5 dates for each group and 5 corresponding count values.
And these 5 dates are all same for all groups.

I want to get groups where the ratio of count in the last date is less than 0.1 compared to counts in all other dates.

Sample data is

| date | Country | City | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-07-09 | France | Paris | 10 |
| 2023-07-11 | France | Paris | 14 |
| 2023-07-12 | France | Paris | 12 |
| 2023-07-13 | France | Paris | 10 |
| 2023-07-14 | France | Paris | 1 |
| 2023-07-09 | France | Nice | 5 |
| 2023-07-11 | France | Nice | 6 |
| 2023-07-12 | France | Nice | 7 |
| 2023-07-13 | France | Nice | 8 |
| 2023-07-14 | France | Nice | 10 |

When I run the query, the expected result is

| Country | City |
| --- | --- |
| France | Paris |

My attempt:

```
WITH joined AS
(SELECT * 
FROM table a OUTER JOIN (select * from table b where b.date = '2023-07-14')
ON a.country = b.country
AND a.city = b.city)

SELECT country, city
FROM joined
WHERE b.count / a.count < 0.1
```

But this gets all groups where the ratio of the count in the last date and other dates is less than 0.1 for at least one date.
Also, I am working with a very large table and wanted to double check if this was the efficient way to do it.

Comment: Please provide sample data, expexted results and a reasonable attempt at solving the problem.

Comment: Hi, I have added sample data, expected results and my attempt at solving the problem.

Comment: I see sample data, not the rest.

Comment: Hi, i have updated my question. Do you see the rest now?

Comment: Is the answer below useful for you ?

Answer (score 0):

It really isn't clear to me what the actual calculation is that you need, I think it is the sum of "count" divided by the number of days (I hope). If so, then this will perform that calculation, but note that the unrounded results are both greater than 0.1

```
SELECT 
       country
     , city
     , sum(a.count)                     sumcount
     , count(*) * 1.0                   numdates
     , count(*) / (sum(a.count) * 1.0 ) calc
FROM your_table a
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM your_table b
    WHERE b.date = '2023-07-14'::date
    AND a.country = b.country
    AND a.city = b.city
    )
GROUP BY
       country
     , city
HAVING count(*) / (sum(a.count) * 1.0 ) > 0.1
```

| country | city | sumcount | numdates | calc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| France | Nice | 36 | 5.0 | 0.13888888888888888889 |
| France | Paris | 47 | 5.0 | 0.10638297872340425532 |

That query (and more) is available at a fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/071tW2Yk)

**nb** The query in the question is invalid syntax